# error obfuscating JavaFX Application with proguard

Tags: java, javafx, proguard, obfuscation, executable-jar

I am not very familiar with proguard, I want to obfuscate a JavaFX application, I already did it right but now after adding some changes to the project things screwed up.

Here is my .pro configuration file :

```
-injars       ../INJAR.jar 
-outjars      ../OUTJAR.jar 

-libraryjars  'rt.jar'
-libraryjars  'jce.jar'
-libraryjars  'jfxrt.jar'


-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-flattenpackagehierarchy ''
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF


-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers


-keep class javax.** { *; }
-keep class impl.** { *; }
-dontwarn impl.**

-keep class org.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.**


-keepclasseswithmembers public class main.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class main.*Controller {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;    
}

-keepclassmembernames class main.NewApplicationController$Applicant {
    public <methods>;
    public <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembernames class main.RDVTaker {
    public <methods>;
}


-obfuscationdictionary members.txt
-classobfuscationdictionary classes.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

by executing the command :
`java -jar obf_data/proguard.jar @obf_data/myconfig.pro > obf_data/info.txt`

I get this erro :

`Error: Unexpected error while writing class [oshi/hardware/platform/mac/MacDisks] (Overflow of unsigned short value [70168])`

I bypassed the above error by removing `-dontshrink` option, but in this case the resulting jar is raising the following  error : `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile OUTJAR.jar`

And by removing both `-dontshrink` and `-dontoptimize` another error get raised, a stacktarce is printed, but I found out that the error was described at this level of stack :

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:
file:/C:/Users/younes/IdeaProjects/vpro/out/artifacts/vpro/OUTJAR.jar.
jar!/main/main.fxml:12
```

I am wondering if someone got a supposition, idea or even another obfuscating tool,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider very carefully if obfuscating is really worth the trouble and pain it is causing you, and, if not, do not obfuscate.

Comment: I am distributing a program which code should be protected at least by obfuscation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the file wasn't present in the OUT file, I worked it around by manually injecting it in the jar zip. Some flags of Proguard may help to keep the file.